# How to copy Database from Asset Folder to Databases Folder

Tags: java, android

My code is as Follows:

dbhelper.java

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion >= newVersion) return;
    db.execSQL("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME +";");
    onCreate(db);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //here is the database definition
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE dhivehienglish " +
            "(mv TEXT, en TEXT);");
    //insert pre-configured records
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO dhivehienglish (mv, en) VALUES('ކާރު','car');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO dhivehienglish (mv, en) VALUES('ޖަހާ','hit');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO dhivehienglish (mv, en) VALUES('އިނުން','sit');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO dhivehienglish (mv, en) VALUES('ކެއުން','eat');");
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carian_kamus);

    //listing data processes
    //-initiate the database connector
    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    txtmelayu=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmelayu);
    btncari=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncari);
    btncari.setOnClickListener(this);
    lblmakna=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblmakna);

}//end onCreate

public void onClick(View v){
    //fetch kata melayu dr textbox
    String carimelayu=txtmelayu.getText().toString();
    //kena letak dalam onclick
    //-run SELECT command to fetch data from table
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btncari){
        Cursor cmelayu=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dhivehienglish " +
                "WHERE mv='"+carimelayu+"';", null);
        //-fetch record
        if(cmelayu.getCount()!=0){
            cmelayu.moveToFirst();//go to first row
            String en=cmelayu.getString(1).toString();
            lblmakna.setText(en);
        }
        else{
            //display some notice here saying no data found
            lblmakna.setText("Not found!");}}

}//end onCLick

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_carian_kamus, menu);
    return true;
}

//when menu is selected
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //call about screen, if user hit "Tentang kami" menu
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.minsert){
        Intent ins= new Intent (this, InsertActivity.class);
        startActivity(ins);
    }
    return true;
}}
```

How can i move my existing Database from my Assets Folder and use it as a native database located within my Application's Sandbox ? Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the answer below and if it has solved your problem, then please do accept it too.

Comment: No showing some kind of error.. database is not copying.. may be i m implementing your code wrongly. can u briefly help me how to put your code in dbhelper.java

Comment: thnk u.. now m trying your updated code.. but there is one more problem.. now when I open the app, there is a search function, when i press search button app force close.. may there is something wrong with mainactivity.java. may be something not matching with your code.. shall i upload my app so you can check the problem.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/t92ccuetiqc1fka/Dhivehi%20English%20Dictionary.zip

Comment: Ok, if your current problem is solved then please accept this answer. I will take a look to your code, after getting back to home.

Comment: any news..? have u checked my code

Comment: I am checking it right now.

Comment: It seems that you are creating a table named `dhivehienglish` and fetching values from table name `rhyan` It was the reason why your app was crashing.

Comment: can u fix it and reupload it.. including your updated script..

Comment: I have uploaded the project for you. Here is the link: https://www.mediafire.com/?79xqqeez8u2b9ol

Comment: wow... thank u so much Salman Khakwani for your work.. am just learning to create an app.. am a newbie to java language.. has no knowledge so am just taking sample notes from this website.. will surely add your name in about page when my app builds successfully..

Comment: my pleasure, keep the good work up :-)

Comment: hey if i want to add autocomplete textview while searching what i need to do..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your `createDataBase()` method in your `DatabaseHandler` like the code below:

**createDataBase() :**

```
 public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            System.out.println("createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}
```

**checkDataBase() :**

```
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

**copyDataBase() :**

```
//Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```

Where `DB_PATH` = `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/Databases/`, You can initialize it in your DatabseHandler's Construct like this : `DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";` 
`DB_NAME` = YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_THAT_IS_STORED_IN_YOUR_ASSETS_FOLDER

I hope this helps.

P.S: DB_NAME and DB_PATH are both Strings.

**UPDATE :** 
Whenever you are trying to use an instance of your `DatabaseHelper` Class, just call this method `createDatabase()` like this :

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
   try 
    {
        db.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException io) 
    {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
```

It will copy the existing Database from Asset Folder if the Database has not been copied to the Databases directory.
I hope this helps.