# Using Pre-populated Database on SQLite database Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

here i want to use my pre-populated SQLite database to my android app. So, when first run it automatically copy the database from assets folder and use it as database on my android app.

I have doing this stuff so far :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String MyVillageSoftware = "MyVillageSoftware";
public static final String table_Question = "table_question";
private static final String DATABASE_PATH="/Users/ever_ncn/Documents/Project/PsikologiKarakter/app/src/main/assets/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="question.db";
//TOL for transaction Coloumn
SQLiteDatabase db;
Context context;
private static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();



public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

public void createDatabase(){
    createDB();
}

public void createDB(){
    boolean dbExist = DBExist();

    if(!dbExist){
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDBFromResource();
    }

}

private boolean DBExist(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try{
        String databasePath = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(databasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("SqlHelper", "Database nda ada babi");
    }
    if(db != null){
        db.close();
    }return db != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDBFromResource(){
    InputStream inStream=null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String dbFilePath=DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
    try{
        inStream=context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        outStream=new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length=inStream.read(buffer))>0){
            outStream.write(buffer, 0 , length);
        }
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
        throw new Error("Problem cuk");
    }
}

public List<String> getAllCategory() {
    List<String> AllCategoryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> AllCategIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + table_Question;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);



    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String Id = cursor.getString(0);
            String A = cursor.getString(1);
            String B = cursor.getString(2);
            String C = cursor.getString(3);
            String D = cursor.getString(4);
            String aExplain = cursor.getString(5);
            String bExplain = cursor.getString(6);
            String cExplain = cursor.getString(7);
            String dExplain = cursor.getString(8);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return AllCategoryList;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_Question);
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

But i got an error message like this :

> 10-28 07:18:38.988    2425-2425/gook.psikologikarakter E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
>   10-28 07:18:38.988    2425-2425/gook.psikologikarakter E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30046: (2) open(/Users/ever_ncn/Documents/Project/PsikologiKarakter/app/src/main/assets/question.db) -
>   10-28 07:18:38.989    2425-2425/gook.psikologikarakter E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/Users/ever_ncn/Documents/Project/PsikologiKarakter/app/src/main/assets/question.db'.
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
>               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
>               at gook.psikologikarakter.DatabaseHelper.DBExist(DatabaseHelper.java:65)
>               at gook.psikologikarakter.DatabaseHelper.createDB(DatabaseHelper.java:52)
>               at gook.psikologikarakter.DatabaseHelper.createDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:48)
>               at gook.psikologikarakter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I don't know what really happen, but i think i can't open the database file. But i don't know what to do. Please master help me.

Thanks before.

Comment: You can't use a database from the assets folder. You'll want to copy the database over to /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/ on first run time. This will be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Comment: yes sir, i mean that, so my question is how to copy the database from assets folder to data/data/your_package/databases/ when the app start for the first time?

Comment: That my friend is as simple as just copying any other file you would using java. Here is one specifically for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20592481/1371041

Comment: but i got error on this sir :
private String DATABASE_PATH= context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

i got error "illegal forward reference"

Comment: @ChallengeAccepted thanks sir, it work very well

Comment: glad to have solved your issue. As for the "illegal forward reference" did you make sure it was in the constructor? What did you do to solve your error?

Comment: i use another pattern code to do that sir.
i use this code sir, private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String DATABASE_PATH="/Users/ever_ncn/Documents/Project/PsikologiKarakter/app/src/main/assets/";
```

This is the path on your local file system, not the path of the file on the device at runtime. Use `getResources().getAssets().openFile(...)` to get an `InputStream`  to the file.

Comment: so is the code gonna be like this sir?
context.getResources().getAssets().openFile(DATABASE_NAME);


but i got an error on openFile();